# Can I stop an element scrolling off the screen with CSS3?

Tags: html, css, scroll, positioning

I have a nested shopping-type list that is grouped by type (and has descriptions for each item).

What I'm wanting to do is have the last type scrolling in the list, until the point that it would scroll off the top of the list.

A list may declared as

```html
<div id="items">
     <item-type>Type A</item-type>
     <description>a</description>
     <description>b</description>
     <description>c</description>
     <item-type>Type B</item-type>
     <description>d</description>
     <description>e</description>
     <description>f</description>
     <description>g</description>
     <description>h</description>
</div>
```

I'm using element types so that I can use `#items > item-type:last-of-type` in CSS3 to select the last element.

```
#items {
word-wrap: break-word;
overflow: auto;
height: 100%;
}

#items > * {
    display: block;
}

#items > item-type:last-of-type {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 100px;   
}
```

So the only point now, is how do I keep it (effectively) `position: relative; top: 0` to `position: absolute; top: 0` using only CSS3?

I'm using FF4 and HTML5, so you can go all out; this won't be supported on older browsers. Also, using [`calc()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc) is fine.

The valid view options are be something like:

```
______________________________________
Type A            a             Type B 
  a               b               e
  b               c               f
  c             Type B            g
                  d               h
---------------------------------------
```

Where the lines are the visible area, and each column shows how it would appear given a certain amount of data (progression left to right)

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, I don't think it's possible with pure CSS3. A few lines of jQuery will work though.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what the end result should be. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Your explanation of the problem is rather chaotic and is hard to understand clearly what you'd like to achieve. I can see there are some scrollings. But are there things like ie. freeze columns/rows in Excel so they don't get scrolled but everything else does? But in the way that last data can't be scrolled off the view port?

Comment: I don't know but maybe what you may be after is `position:fixed`?

Comment: I've updated with a diagram for each stage. `position:fixed` is not great due to column 2 layout; I want to see the previous items (or as many as possible), but always want to see the last heading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you want to create something like the iPhone *Contacts* list. Looking at the solution [someone already built](http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/the_iphone_contacts_app_with_css_and_jquery.html) it uses JavaScript. Also, I've thought about it and gone through all the CSS3 specs but cannot determine anything that could be used here to achieve the same affect without JavaScript.

I knocked up a [small demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GzsUt/2/), but again this uses JavaScript. I just don't think it's possible with pure CSS, although I'm sure someone will correct me if that's not the case :-)

**HTML**

```
<div id="items">
    <item-type>Type A</item-type>
    <description>a</description>
    <description>b</description>
    <description>c</description>
    <item-type>Type B</item-type>
    <description>d</description>
    <description>e</description>
    <description>f</description>
    <description>g</description>
    <description>h</description>
    <description>i</description>
    <description>j</description>
    <description>k</description>
    <description>l</description>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#items {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow: auto;
    height:100px;
    border:1px dashed red;
    width:200px;
}

#items > * {
    display: block;
}

#items > item-type {
    border:1px dashed blue;
    background-color:#fff;
    width:180px;
}
```

**JavaScript** (jQuery 1.6+)

```
var itemsTop = $('#items').position().top;
var itemTypeHeight = $('item-type').height();
var itemTypeBottom = itemsTop + itemTypeHeight;

$('#items').scroll(function() {
    $('item-type').each(function() {
        $(this).css({position:''});

        if ($(this).position().top < itemsTop + itemTypeHeight) {
            $(this).css({position:'fixed',top:itemsTop});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I'll give you the tick :).  I was just coming back to say it's not really possible...

Comment: Thanks. It would be nice to see a pure CSS solution one day!

Comment: Don't know how likely when firefox talks about dropping min and max support (can't find the page atm :()

Comment: Yes I read about that yesterday whilst researching this answer :-) [Bugzilla #363249](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=363249#c83) and [this thread](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2010Sep/thread.html#msg233) have the relevant discussions.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible for the following reasons (which may or may not be related):

- When in normal viewing, a `relative` position is needed; at the top of the visible area, it would need to change to `absolute`
- you could use `calc()` and `min()` or `max()` with the visible height, the current element's height and the current scroll position; except that none of these calculated properties are available to css
- Another idea is making more absolute positioning of the 2nd item level, but there's no way of referencing the absolute-parent's height as well as the absolute-grandparent's height.

I think the first point is the easiest way to convince myself that it's not possible. The other two convince me that combinations of fancy css functions and absolute positioning are sunk as well.